# converting one input type to another input action in javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
function rotate(value)
{
document.getElementById('div1').style.webkitTransform="rotate(" + value + "deg)";
document.getElementById('div1').style.msTransform="rotate(" + value + "deg)";
document.getElementById('div1').style.MozTransform="rotate(" + value + "deg)";
document.getElementById('div1').style.OTransform="rotate(" + value + "deg)";
document.getElementById('div1').style.transform="rotate(" + value + "deg)";
document.getElementById('span1').innerHTML=value + "deg";
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#div1
{
width:120px;
height:100px;
background-color:yellow;
border:1px solid black;
transform:rotate(7deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(7deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotate(7deg); /* Safari 3-8 */
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<h1>The transform Property</h1>

<p>Rotate the yellow div element:</p>

<div id="div1">HELLO</div>

Rotate: <br>
<input type="range" min="-360" max="360" value="50" onchange="rotate(this.value)" /><br>
transform: rotate(<span id="span1">7deg</span>);

</body>
</html>
```

In the example above how can I take the number as input from the user rather than using that slider and rotate the box using that input. I tried doing it but I think i have to create another function to store the value first and then call it. Please let me know if there is any solution

Comment: Do you mean you want to use a text input instead of a slider?

Answer (score 1):

> Edited.

```html
<script>
    function rotate() {
     var value = document.getElementById('myInput').value; 
     document.getElementById('div1').style.webkitTransform = "rotate(" + value + "deg)";
      document.getElementById('div1').style.msTransform = "rotate(" + value + "deg)";
      document.getElementById('div1').style.MozTransform = "rotate(" + value + "deg)";
      document.getElementById('div1').style.OTransform = "rotate(" + value + "deg)";
      document.getElementById('div1').style.transform = "rotate(" + value + "deg)";
      document.getElementById('span1').innerHTML = value + "deg";
    }
</script>
<style>
    #div1 {
      width: 120px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: yellow;
      border: 1px solid black;
      transform: rotate(7deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(7deg);
      /* IE 9 */
      -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg);
      /* Safari 3-8 */
    }
</style>
<h1>The transform Property</h1>
<p>Rotate the yellow div element:</p>
Rotate:
<input type="text" min="-360" max="360" value="50" id="myInput" /><br> transform: rotate(<span id="span1">50deg</span>);<br>
<button onClick="rotate();">Change</button>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="div1">HELLO</div>
```